# Create JavaScript function without parameter and use dot to pass data

Tags: javascript, function, methods, dot

I want to make a function that instead of using a parameter, it will get the value before the dot like any JavaScript method works. This is what I have that works using a parameter...

```
var myElement = document.getElementsByTagName('DIV')[0];

setToBlack(myElement);

function setToBlack(element) {
    element.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
}
```

However I would like to do this were the element is passed without using any parameter and is declared before the dot. This example does not work and I am struggling to get it to work. Any advice will be most appreciated. I am sure this has been asked on stackoverflow before but I am unable to find it with searching since I am unsure of the proper definitions on what this is called.

```
var myElement = document.getElementsByTagName('DIV')[0];

myElement.setToBlack();

function setToBlack() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
}
```

Comment: Well, `setToBlack` is not a method (function property) of the `myElement` object. You cannot access it through `myElement.setToBlack`, so you cannot invoke it as a method like that either.

Comment: "*I am unsure of the proper definitions on what this is called*" - it's a method call, or method invocation.

Comment: @Triby. I think this is what I am looking for. Are these called javascript methods instead of javascript functions?

Comment: They are called methods because they belongs to an object (object, class, HTMLElement, etc.) and _normal functions_ doesn't.

Comment: Which should I use? Element.prototype... or HTMLElement.prototype...

Answer (score 1):

You could write a wrapper class like this

### OPTION 1

```
class ElementWrapper {
    constructor(element) {
      this.element = element;
    }
  
  setToBlack() {
    this.element.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
  }
  
}

// Use the wrapper class
const targetElement = document.getElementsByTagName('DIV')[0];
const wrappedElement = new ElementWrapper(targetElement);
wrappedElement.setToBlack();
```

### OPTION 2

```
function setToBlack() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
}

const element = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
element.setToBlack = setToBlack;

element.setToBlack();
```

Comment: Is there a way to the executing code simple just like `myElement.setToBlack();`? Which has the "clean" javascript syntax? I was planning on having the function in a seperate JS file and being able to call the function simply using `myElement.setToBlack();` in a different JS file.

Comment: See my edited response.

Comment: @bhutto54  Kindly upvote and accept the answer. It will help your reputation as well. :)